# Expose StorageItems to other pallets whose types are bound on an instance of my pallet

Tags: storage, macro, config

I have a pallet `pallet-a` whose StorageItem should be read/written by other pallets. Let's say that `StorageItem` is

```rust
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn get_commitments)]
    pub type Commits<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageDoubleMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        CommitKey
        Commitment<T::Hash>,
        OptionQuery,
    >;
```

In a separate pallet, `pallet-b`(and in the future, when others use this), the functions of this StorageItem, should be accessible under the namespace of one of `pallet-b`'s Config associated types.

I'm trying to accomplish this result by having `pallet-b`'s Config include some associated types that are bound on traits implemented in the instance of `pallet-a`. As of now, those traits just implement some functions that don't need to be elaborated on here. Just know there are `impl`s for my `Pallet` for each. E.g. just imagine something like

```rust
    impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> Reveal<T::AccountId, T::Hash,> for Pallet<T, I> {
        fn does_thing(
            original_hash: T::Hash,
            random_seed: u64,
        ) -> <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash {
// ... implementation
        }
```

The relevant portion of `pallet-b`'s config trait:

```rust
                    /* --snip-- */
type Commitments: Reveal<<Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <Self as frame_system::Config>::Hash>
+ Commit<Self::AccountId, <Self as pallet::Config>::Hash>;
                    /* --snip-- */
```

And: relevant portion in `Config` trait implementation in `runtime/lib.rs`:

```rust
                    /* --snip-- */
    type Commitments = Commitments; // instance of our pallet implementing traits above
                    /* --snip-- */
```

Now, I'd like to be able to invoke functions on StorageItems inside of `pallet-b` like:

```rust
T::Commitments::Commits::<T, I>::contains_key(k1, k2);
```

But I'm skeptical of the approach based on errors when trying this like:
`help: use fully-qualified syntax: <<T as pallet::Config>::Commitments as Trait>::RevealWindow`.

Bonus:
I also tried adding the above-mentioned StorageItem to the trait like

```rust
    impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> Reveal<T::AccountId, T::Hash,> for Pallet<T, I> {
        type Commits = Commits<T, I>;
                    /* --snip-- */
```

And in `pallet-b`:

```rust
<<T as pallet::Config>::Commitments as Reveal<T::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>::Commits::contains_key(1, 2);
```

which gives:     `` = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `<<T as pallet::Config>::Commitments as pallet_commitments::Reveal<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>::Commits: frame_support::storage::generator::StorageMap<_, _>` which is required by `<<T as pallet::Config>::Commitments as pallet_commitments::Reveal<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>::Commits: frame_support::StorageMap<_, _> ``(Repeating for every type of StorageItem)

I would appreciate any guidance on what I'm trying to accomplish. Can it be done through some particular trait bounds in `pallet-b`'s `Config` trait, or does it need to be an associated type on the trait in `pallet-a`? Or is a different approach recommended?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your trait approach is correct.
The only way of how Pallets are supposed to interact with each other, be it storage or calls, is through traits.
So you cannot use a storage Item of `PalletA` in `PalletB`. This does just not make sense from a pallet perspective - since pallets are sovereign and independent.
`PalletB` should not have the possibility to just invalidate the state invariants of `PalletA`. Otherwise `PalletA` will not work correctly.

One way is put your storage accesses into a trait and then implementa that in `PalletA`. So `T::Commitments::Commits::<T, I>::contains_key(k1, k2);` becomes `T::CommitmentProvider::has_commitment(k1, k2)` or however you want to call it.
You can then have a `CommitmentProvider` and `CommitmentStorer` trait which provides and stores commitments respectively - both being implemented by `PalletA`.